# OpenglES 2.0 issue on iphone 5s with IOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios7, opengl-es-2.0

I'm writing a piece of software involving OpenGL ES 2.0. *It's just about presenting photos with some addon special effects using GLSL.*

Everything worked fine and the shaders performed well on iPhone 4, iPhone 4s and iPhone 5 with IOS7. But when I tested the software with an iPhone 5S with IOS7 installed, OpenGL only gives me the clear color (able to change with glClearColor) for all the GLSL shaders I wrote. Not able to work on the latest device is certainly not acceptable.

Another abnormal phenomenon on iPhone 5S is that **every first call to *glDrawElements*** (I'm using VBO if that matters) **after the used opengl program is compiled** (a new opengl shader program is compiled each time the user switches the special effect), **will block** the current thread for about 10 seconds.

I tried to compile with XCode 5 and 4.6, and both gave the same result (Fine on all devices other than iPhone 5s).

The project work on IOS7 installed on iPhone 5, so the problem shouldn't be the os version or SDK version. I suspect that the new GPU might be the cause, but I have no idea of how to fix it or even test out where in the code is failing. It took me a whole day to only finding out that *glDrawElements* issue.

The code of the software is huge and it's impossible for me to post all it in my question. I will be grateful if anyone can provide me with some help or just some idea.

To make the question more consice, my OpenGL shaders seems to fail on the latest iPhone GPU. So I'm wondering if:

- The latest Apple A7 GPU cut off supports to some OpenGL ES 2.0 features
- There are some limitations on creating vertex buffer objects (vbo) with iPhone 5s
- The use of RenderBuffer, FrameBuffer and TextureBuffer (used to perform multipass shader)  have any difference on iPhone 5s

These are all the suspicious part I can think of now, but I have no idea how to test them, because I'm not getting even one rendered frame by now.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the 5S has extremely lazy state setup and/or strict validation rules that the 5 did not have. Usually when you bind a resource and use it for the first time and it takes an excessively long time, it is due in part to deferred setup/allocation and validation. Do not be quick to blame `glDrawElements (...)`, the number of seemingly unrelated operations that are finally committed when you make a draw call would surprise you. It probably has nothing to do with your vertex data, and everything to do with resource allocation / validation.

Comment: thx for your tip. btw, I didn't find any document talking about the difference of opengl between 5s and it's priors. I'd be glad if you can provide me some. @AndonM.Coleman

Comment: I also have users reporting similar problems with IOS app. The OpenGLES 2.0 GLKView shows up grey/clear on iPhone 5s but not on any other Apple devices. I am still trying to determine the cause. First step was upgrading development environment to Xcode 5 & IOS 7 SDK.

Comment: I figured out my problem some how. First of all, upgrading XCode & SDK is considerable, but it didn't help. I figured out that the OpenGLES implementation on the new iPhone 5s GPU is much more strict than before. My app began to work again when I wrapped my VBOs with VAO, and changed all the ints in my shaders to floats. I'm still not sure why this would do the job, but the illness is cured for now.

Answer (score 1):

The big difference between the iPhone 5 and the 5S is the 64-bit architecture. I am seeing problems in my app now that deal with passing floats to the shaders. In 64-bit mode, when I pass in 0.8 it gets to the shader as -1.58819e-23. I am about to open a new question regarding the issue, but you might want to check your values at runtime using the OpenGL ES Frame Capture.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-debugger/articles/debugging_opengl_es_frame.html